# Class structure guaranteed to be the order of access

Tags: c++

Consider this:

```
class Vec3
{
    private:
        float n[3];
    public:
        float& x;
        float& y;
        float& z;
        Vec3(float x_, float y_, float z_) : x(n[0]), y(n[1]), z(n[2])
        {
            x = x_;
            y = y_;
            z = z_;
        }
}
```

can I be sure that doing this:

```
Vec3 v(1,2,3);
cout<<reinterpret_cast<float*>(&v)[0]<<"\t";
cout<<reinterpret_cast<float*>(&v)[1]<<"\t";
cout<<reinterpret_cast<float*>(&v)[2]<<"\t";
```

will give me `1 2 3` by every compiler/OS that follows the standard?

Comment: what does it print out on your compiler, once you fix the compiler errors?

Comment: @juancho: That's the most irrelevant thing you can imagine.

Comment: @DeadMG I can imagine more irrelevant things. Maybe it is just my wild imagination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in other answers, this won't work, because of the `float&`. See [Standard Layout Classes and Trivially Copyable Types](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=565) for a long explanation about standard layout.

You could consider a slightly different approach:

```
class Vec3
{
    private:
        float n[3];
    public:
        float& x() { return n[0]; }
        float& y() { return n[1]; }
        float& z() { return n[2]; }
        Vec3(float x_, float y_, float z_)
        {
            x() = x_;
            y() = y_;
            z() = z_;
        }
};
```

Thus,

```
Vec3 v(1,2,3);
cout<<reinterpret_cast<float*>(&v)[0]<<"\t";
cout<<reinterpret_cast<float*>(&v)[1]<<"\t";
cout<<reinterpret_cast<float*>(&v)[2]<<"\t";
```

Will print `1 2 3` for all compilers

**Edit**

You might also want to see [What are Aggregates and PODs (1st answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special/4178176#4178176) and [What are Aggregates and PODs (2nd answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special/7189821#7189821) for more precise information.

Comment: can I define a ctor on a POD type?

Comment: @Luke
C++03: No, by definition POD types can't have user defined constructor.
C++11: You can define a constructor for a POD type if you specify a non-user default constructor (ie, `MyClass() = default;`)
See my edited post

Answer (score 5):

No. For that to work, you'd need (at least) a standard-layout type. `float&` isn't, and therefore `Vec3` isn't either. (9/7, first bullet).

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Your class is not POD, so there are no guarantees whatsoever, AFAIK.

Comment: It is the standard-layout property that is most important here (which is in cluded in the PODness)

Comment: @PlasmaHH: But this isn't standard-layout either (standard layout requires that all non-static members have the same access specifier, but this has both public and private members).

Comment: @JerryCofin: as I said, "which is included in PODness".